# BitBucket: Cross Reference between commits and issues not working

Tags: git, bitbucket, git-commit

I just activate the issue tracker within one of my repositories on bitbucket.

I also entered issues successfully. However, when I commited new code to the repository fixing a bug the corresponding issue gets resolved but in the commits list there is no cross reference to the bug as explained [here](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/resolve-issues-automatically-when-users-push-code-221451126.html)

The commit message I used was:

```
git commit -m 'Bug fix #1: messages with special characters are displayed correctly'
```

The following images shows you that I don't have the reference in the list of commits proposed by the link above. I also checked the Services in the settings - there I have the Issues listed as service.

[image: test]

Have I overlooked something?

Answer (score 1):

I think it's the ordering of your words. only certain syntax commands activate the linking. In this case, I think "fix bug #1" changes the status of the bug (which adds a comment to the commit) and references the bug in the commit log, but "bug fix #1" only changes the status (and comment in commit). Try reversing those words, or check this [guide](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/set-up-the-issues-service-223216615.html).

Answer (score 0):

Use `Resolved #issue_number` in the commit message